# Network Menu missing in Menu Bar in 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04

After upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS, the Network menu in my global menu bar has disappeared. I haven't been able to find any documentation outlining how to debug system menu items. How do I get this menu item back?

Another issue that may be a symptom of the same problem is that the "Options" button under the wired networking preferences pane no longer does anything.

I've checked that `indicator-network` is installed.

Comment: See if the package `indicator-network` is installed and then update your question, thanks!

Comment: Note that this might happen when you connect via VNC. Your vnc startup script might not work correctly and that is why you don't see network menu and cannot run `nm-applet` as a normal user. Try connecting directly to check if that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link for the same issue with Lubuntu,may be of some help  http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/fix-lubuntu-1404-network-manager.html

Comment: Thanks, that was able to help me figure out the issue. I needed to reinstall the package `network-manager-gnome`, it was somehow removed during the system upgrade.